# Is it ever a good idea to have a record in a reference table in your database that represent "all other records"?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, database-design, database-schema

I have an asp.net-mvc website with a SQL Server backend. I am simplifying my situation to highlight and isolate the issue. I have 3 tables in the DB

1. Article table (id, name, content)
2. Location table (id, name)
3. ArticleLocation table  (id, article Id, location Id)

On my website, when you create an article, you select from a multiselect listbox the locations where you want that article sent.

There are about 25 locations so I was debating adding a new location called "Global" as a shortcut instead of having the person select 25 different items from a listbox.  I could still do this as a shortcut on the front end but now I am debating if there is benefit for this to flow through to the backend.

So if I have an article that goes global, instead of having 25 records in the ArticleLocation table, I would only have one and then I would do some tricks on the front end to select all of the items.  I am trying to figure out if this is a very bad idea.

Things I can think about that are making me nervous:

1. what if I create an article and choose global but then last in the future 3 new locations are added.  Without this global setting, these 3 location would not get the article but in the new way, they would.  I am not sure what is better as the second thing might actually be what you want but its a little less explicit.
2. I have a requirement on a report, I want to filter by all articles that are global. Imagine I would need a article.IsGlobal() methode. Right now I guess I could say if a project has the same count of locations as all of the records in the location table I could translate that to being deemed global but again since people can add new locations, I feel like this approach is somewhat flaky.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this dilemna around creating records in a reference data table that really reflect "all records".  Appreciate any advice

Comment: No matter which way you choose, you will be defining a requirement that you might not want to: whether new locations will automatically get an article that was defined when that location didn't yet exist. So it seems like if you're going to use a global flag you should also add an attribute about whether it inherits new locations or not (or make that a property of the location).

Comment: Perhaps it is clearer to add an `AllLocations` flag to the `Article` table.  Any article with the flag set to `1` appears in all locations, regardless of when they were created, and need not have any entries in the `ArticleLocation` table.  An article can still be explicitly added to all _existing_ locations if the author does not want it to automatically appear in future locations.  You can hide some of the fun behind views, and can add a trigger to enforce a rule that either an article applies everywhere or in specific locations, but not both.

Comment: Keep it simple and either use @HABO's suggestion or go with your first instinct to add a "GLOBAL" record in the location table. I would only go with more advanced solutions if you started creating shortcuts for various reason, i.e., "EUROPE", "AMERICAS"...etc.

Comment: I wonder why most complicated answers got most upvotes :) Seems that SO people prefer complex technical rebuses over very simple and efficient solutions :-)

Comment: If tables are relatively simple, i will allow locationId to be null in ArticleLocation, and null entry will mean its not dependent on location and hence global. Seems logical to me too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By request, here is my comment promoted to an answer.  It's an opportunity to expand on it, too.

I'll limit my answer to a system with a single list of locations. I've done the corporate hierarchy thing: Companies, Divisions, Regions, States, Counties, Offices and employees or some such. It gets ugly.

In the case of the OP's question, it seems that adding an `AllLocations` bit to the `Articles` table makes the intention clear. Any article with the flag set to 1 appears in all locations, regardless of when they were created, and need not have any entries in the `ArticleLocation` table. An article can still be explicitly added to all existing locations if the author does not want it to automatically appear in future locations.

Implementation involves a little more work.  I would add `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers to the `Article` and `ArticleLocation` tables to enforce the rule that either the `AllLocations` bit is set and there are no corresponding rows in `ArticleLocation`, or the bit is clear and locations may be explicitly set. (It's a personal preference to have the database defend itself against "bad data" whenever it's practical to do so.)

Depending on your needs, a table-valued function is a good way to hide some of the dirty work, e.g. `dbo.GetArticleIdsForLocation( LocationId )` can handle the `AllLocations` flag internally. You can use it in stored procedures and ad-hoc queries to `JOIN` with `Article`. In other cases a view may be appropriate.

Another feature that you are welcome to borrow ("Steal from your friends!") is to have the administrator's landing page be an "exceptions" page. It's a place where I display things that vary from massive flaming disasters to mere peccadillos. In this case, articles that are associated with zero locations would qualify as something non-critical, but worth checking up on.

Articles that are *explicitly* shown in every location might be of interest to someone adding a new location, so I would probably have a web page for that. It may be that some of the articles should be updated to account for the new location explicitly or reconsidered for being changed to all locations.

Comment: This is a very clean solution from a pure database standpoint.  However, consider the side effects on the full stack: the UI now requires a hardcoded dropdown entry called "Global", and also the server side code has to generate two slightly different sql queries depending if the user chose "Global" or any of the other entries.  I don't mean to poo-poo on this answer at all, just wanted to add the full considerations.

Comment: @DanLing - I'd be inclined to add a checkbox to the UI to allow the user to explicitly designate the article as applying to all locations, present and future. When checked it should disable the other choices, whether that is a multi-select list or an array of checkboxes for each location. Yes, it's more complicated, but it should make it abundantly clear to the user that they are doing something different. Depending on the number of locations and typical dispersal of articles I might also have buttons to check all or none. [POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: Oops, for some reason I thought the OP said having "global" in the dropdown was a requirement.

Comment: @DanLing - As for the database side, such is life. Whether it is a global flag or a magic location, the database needs to have some awareness of what is going on. As a rule, I prefer solutions with a reduced magic content. By using stored procedures all of the details can be tested at a clearly defined interface. On a good day the implementation can be changed while keeping the stored procedure interface intact.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense to me.  It's kind of like in many calendar applications, there is a difference between "All day event" and events with a specific time range.

Comment: @DanLing - I don't read the OP as stating that having "Global" in the list box is a _requirement_. As for my UI preferences, having spent quite some time in the world of industrial automation I'm a little more sensitive to some details. You only have to spill the molten steel once for people to get upset.

Comment: @HABO, why not using a bit-array column that holds whatever locations the article belongs to? That would be a lot more flexible solution (you could then select any subset of locations for any article), a lot more efficient (won't require OR in queries, nor will it require you to work with datasets - your idea of the getArticleIdsForLocations), a whole table will then become unnecessary (ArticleLocations; along with its indices & foreign keys) and have the entire system use a lot less JOIN operations (which is good if a NoSQL db is an option that might be considered in the future).

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner - As locations are added the table schema could be changed to enlarge the bit array, or just throw in an arbitrarily large `VARBINARY` column and hope it isn't exceeded. The fact that TSQL bitwise operators do not support operations on two binary string arguments ([Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)) makes handling more than 64 locations harder than it ought to be. Since the question was tagged `sql-server` I didn't worry much about MUMPS or NoSQL. And the bit array can't express "all locations" unless you set all future bits to one.

Comment: @HABO, you're right, but what if the number of locations can be upper bounded by 64...? Isn't it something that's worth considering...?

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner - What is the balance of reads and writes? Average locations per article? Number of articles? Number of global articles? Query rate? Query complexity? Acceptable latency? Available memory for caching? ... You may be heading toward premature optimization. _Do a benchmark using typical database operations that anyone can maintain._ If there is a problem, quantify it, redesign, and remeasure. If you have different requirements, e.g. all open source software or it must run on an Arduino, then you are solving a different problem with different constraints.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it ever a good idea ... that represent “all other records”?

Is it it ever a good idea to represent a **tree** in table? *Root* of a tree represents “all other records”.

Trees and hierarchies are not simple to work with, but there are many examples, articles and books that tackle the problem -- like Celko's *Trees and Hierarchies in SQL*; Karwin's *SQL Antipatterns*.

So what you actually have here is a hierarchy (maybe just a tree) -- it may help to approach the problem that way from the start. The `Global` from your example is just another `Location` (root of a tree), so when a new location is added, you may decide if it will be a child of the `Global` or not.

---

**Facts**

- *Location*(LocationID) exists.
- *Location*(LocationID) is contained in *Parent Location*(LocationID).
- *Article*(ArticleID) exists.
- *Article*(ArticleID) is available at *Location*(LocationID).

**Constraints**

- `Each` *Location* is contained in `at most one` *Parent Location*. `It is possible that for some` *Parent Location*, `more than one` *Location* is contained in `that` *Parent Location*.
- `It is possible that some` *Article* is available at `more than one` *Location*
  `and that for some` *Location*, `more than one` *Article* is available at `that` *Location*.

---

**Logical**

[image]

---

This way you can assign any location to an article -- but **have to resolve it to the leaf level** when needed.

The hierarchy (tree) is here represented in the "naive way"; use closure table, nested sets or enumerated path instead -- or, if you like recursion...

Comment: What does it mean when an article is associated with both a location and the location's parent?

Comment: @PhilipKelley -- this is what **have to resolve it to the leaf level** means. Possible redundancy has to be dealt with, means that there is a `select distinct ArticleID, LocationID` ...

Comment: parent location doesn't really fit as every other record will have the same parent  . .  i am all for storing trees in a db table but this is not really a tree . .

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

In this case as I understand it, I think it is a good idea to create a "global" location in the Location table. I definitely find it preferable to creating a "global" flag in the Article table.

---

"Is it ever a good idea...?" is not a question we like to answer on SO.  It's mostly a debate question, not a Q&A question, and besides, we have enough creativity in our community to come up with *some* example where "it" would be a good idea, regardless.

To your more specific question, *how do I represent "all locations" in the database?* that is a judgement call based on your business requirements.

#### Do you want "all locations" to include future locations?

If not, then probably you should only implement "all locations" as a helper that selects all current locations in the database.

#### Do you anticipate having a hierarchy of locations?

Real-world locations have significant hierarchy:

- Global
- Multi-national (continent, trading block)
- Country
- Administrative region (state, province, canton, etc.)
- City
- Neighborhood

If you think you are going to want to have the option to choose, say, a Country, instead of Global, then implementing a hierarchical representation such as Damir suggests is the best way to go. However, if you are not sure if you are ever going to have any other grouping of locations besides Global, a hierarchical data structure is too much work for now.  All you need to do is make sure your current implementation has a migration path to a possible future hierarchical representation.

## Global as a pseudo-location

If you *do* want future locations included in Global and *do not* need a hierarchical location structure, then my instinct based on years of experience would be to create "Global" as a pseudo-location.  That is, Global would be one of the locations in the Location table, but it would have a special meaning.  This is definitely a trade-off, but has the benefit of *not* altering the data structure to support Global which means that all the special cases that "Global" creates are handled by excluding or including some Locations in queries rather than by checking some flags somewhere.  (Or if you like flags, you can add a 'pseudo-location' flag to the Location table.)

With Global as a location, additions or deletions to the Location table are handled automatically.  The query for all Global articles is straightforward: the same as the query for all articles for any other Location.  Reporting on articles by location is also straight forward, with Global articles appearing in reports just like any other location.  You can also represent the difference between a "Global" article (all current and future locations) and an "all locations" article (all current locations but *no* future locations).

Selecting all articles that should be visible at a specific location is slightly harder, it's now a check against "Global" as well as that location, but at least it is checking for 2 values in the same table versus checking two different tables.

```
SELECT article_id FROM ArticleLocation WHERE location_id in (1, 5);
```

vs

```
SELECT article_id FROM ArticleLocation WHERE location_id = 5
UNION
SELECT id FROM Article WHERE is_global;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the logic, as you described it, GLOBAL should be actually global and stay global, even if you add new locations (problem 1 solved). But this also implies that GLOBAL is not the same thing as "all locations" (as there might also exist some other locations we don't have defined yet). I think this logic is needed especially by your requirement 2 - otherwise it would completely fail on adding new locations.

Analysis done! From the above we see that GLOBAL is something above all those locations. There's no sense in trying to define it as a Location. Go for the easiest solution!

- Article table (id, name, content, **global**)

i.e. boolean flag - article is global or not. In the UI, **do it simply as a checkbox** - if checked, the multiselect box will be disabled. Simple, easy, requirements met. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to automatically add some articles to new locations when new locations are added? If yes then in such case I’d consider adding new ‘global’ property in the backend.

Otherwise it probably isn’t worth the effort. Even if you had 10000 articles and 20 different locations selected for each article that would be about 200k records which is not that bad when you set indexes.

Check your existing data and see how people are already choosing locations. If most users select only several locations and not all then it’s really an edge case and you shouldn’t be working on it unless it really creates problems.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @HABO's comment (he should have posted it--if he does, upvote him). Adding an atrribute to table Article to identify those items that are to be associated with all Locations, present *and* future, presumably for the lifetime of the article, should save you time and effort over the long run. Sure, triggers and counts-against-all will do the trick, but they're awkward and would be a pain to support if/when subsequent system changes come along. The UI would be simpler to use, as the user just has to click a checkbox (or whatever) and not multi-click everything in a dropdown of unforseeable length.

(@Damir's hierarchy idea would work as well, but--speaking from a bit too much experience--they're a hassle to work with, and I wouldn't introduce one here unless there was significantly more system and/or business use to get out of it.)